# Java Mail API - "Do not Forward" permission setting

Tags: java, api, email, permissions

I am trying send the email using java mail API and want to enable the option "Do not Forward" under permission (in outlook 2007) while sending email. Can you please suggest me some pointers to do it?

I dont want the user to forward , print copy the email .

is there any attribute setting for this ? (e.g. to send mail with high priority x-priority is used)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for the MS Exchange Information Rights Management settings within MAPI or SMTP. These are Outlook/Exchange centric settings, and you would have to write something using their object model (which I believe is all COM / .Net based with no direct Java access other than via JNI). Furthermore, if you are sending these message to non-outlook clients, it won't matter. E.g. Gmail is not going to prevent

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpmsg basically what's been said.  You can find some information on the wiki. though, it doesn't look like there is a lot in the ways of creating this file yourself and attaching it.